# In "sftp" how to upload all files, but not (sub)folders

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, ftp, sftp

In an `sftp` session, is there a way for me to `put` the contents of a folder, but only files (not subfolders)? Here's an example.

```
Folder
    main.py
    config.py
    requirements.txt
    __pycache__ (a folder)
```

Above is a sample of the local directory. From the folder that encloses `Folder`, I'd SFTP to the target server. How do I `put` only `main.py`, `config.py`, and `requirements.txt` (they're files not folders)? . I don't want to put `__pycache__` as it's a folder.

If I `put -r Folder` it will copy `Folder` and all its contents, including `__pycache__`. If I `put -r Folder/*`, it will put all the contents of `Folder`, without `Folder` itself, including `__pycache__`. This is close to what I want. A variant of `put -r Folder/*` that only copies file contents, not subfolders. So it would skip the  `__pycache__` folder when copying contents.

Thanks!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Bingo!! Thanks a ton, worked like a charm. I guess the lack of an `-r` implies not to deal with folders _at all_. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `-r` if you do not want to ***r**ecurse* into the subdirectories:

```
put Folder/*
```